# Qt Quick Controls 2 application crashes when Qt.quit()

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I'm using Qt Quick Controls 2 to develop my new application. Recently I encountered a severe problem as described below:

**Problem:** When I call Qt.quit() in a clicked handler of a button, the application will mostly crash. Debugging into the code, I found it crash when running into qquick_syncback_helper (in qquickanimatorjob.cpp). My demo code is quit simple:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")


    Button{
        text: "quit"
        onClicked: Qt.quit()
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
}
```

Anyone has any ideas?

**PS:** It is found that if clicking on the button very quickly, the application would quit normally, while almost crash when clicking slowly on the button(when the animation on the button shows up).

**PPS:** I'm using Qt Creator 4.2.2 on Windows 10 64bit with Qt 5.8.0 for VS 2015 64bit and using Qt Quick Controls 2 with Material Style 2.1. I haven't tried Qt 5.9.0 yet, but I'm going to figure it out soon.

Comment: Based on the problem description, it sounds like you are using the Material style and Qt 5.8.0, but could you clarify these in the question? Which platform are you using? Could you try with the latest Qt 5.9.0 beta available in the online installer?

Comment: Why do you say crash? What message do you have?

Comment: It doesn't crash for me, any way I press the button. Maybe a faulty Qt installation. I am using GCC thou.

Comment: I recall some fixes and changes to both, the Material style's ripple animation in Qt Quick Controls 2, and the animation framework in Qt Quick core, so you might want to try with the latest Qt 5.9 beta which is straight-forward to install from the online installer.

Answer (score -3):

used this:

```
onPressed: Qt.quit()
```

Comment: Explain your answer please

Comment: used  `onPressed` replace `onClicked`

Comment: why? What improvement does it have with respect to `onClicked`?

Comment: In SO we do not like questions that are just code, you must give a brief explanation.

Comment: if you want to know why? report this questions to `bugreports.qt.io`